# How to make consumer thread work when items are added to an initially empty queue?

Tags: multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

I am new to ptyhon and currently exploring Multi threading. This program takes a list. t1 (producer) generates random numbers and if the difference between the generated number and the original number from the list is less than 10, it will add the generated number to a queue and then print the generated number. The thread t2 (consumer) takes the number from the queue reverses it and by the same process finds the closest random number and prints it.

```
import threading
import random
import time
import queue

liss = [563869, 9432, 692, 638221,565952,23,1458,998,6942623]
q=queue.Queue()
# q.put(111)
event=threading.Event()
def mtch(liss):
    for n in liss:
        j = 0
        ti1 = time.time()
        k = random.randint(0, 100000000)
        while abs(k - n) > 10:
            k = random.randint(0, 100000000)
        ti2 = time.time()
        q.put(n)
        print(f"{k} found in {ti2 - ti1} seconds,{q.qsize()}")
        
def unmtch(q):
    while not q.empty():
        n=q.get()
  
        m=int(str(n)[::-1])
        j = 0
        ti3 = time.time()
        k = random.randint(0, 100000000)
        while abs(k - m) > 10:
            k = random.randint(0, 100000000)
        ti4 = time.time()
        print(f"Rematch for {n} found in {ti4 - ti3} seconds,{q.qsize()}")


t1=threading.Thread(target=mtch,args=[liss])
t2=threading.Thread(target=unmtch,args=(q,))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

The thread t2 will work only when there are items in the queue. But even when t1 is generating items in queue 'q' the thread t2 is not working. If I initiate a item in the queue at the very begining (for example  q.put(111)) the size of the queue is not equal to zero and then the thread t2 works, i.e., it is generating closest numbers for items of the queue. However if t2 works faster than t1 and if the size of queue thus becomes 0 even for once, t2 stops working even when t1 produces fresh item for the queue later.